# What degenerative disease did the Baron have?

Tags: dune

(Spoilers for various Dune books)

In the Dune Encyclopedia entry for

> Reverend Mother Gaius Helen Mohiam

it is [said](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Gaius_Helen_Mohiam) that she infects

> Baron Vladimir Harkonnen

with a degenerative disease which can be covered up by

> eating excessively

What was the disease?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cause of Baron Harkonnen's pustules in 'Dune' (1984)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153626/what-is-the-cause-of-baron-harkonnens-pustules-in-dune-1984)

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi: Obviously not - we are talking about a disease which can be covered up by over-eating.

Comment: -1 For gratuitous use of spoiler tags.

Comment: @Lexible: Feel free to edit so as to better utilize them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Baron's 'disease' isn't adressed in the original novels (beyond mentioning that he's very fat) but it was in the prequel novel co-written by his son. Note that the *specific* disease isn't mentioned, nor does it fit the description of any contemporary plague. Clearly it's something either very rare or something that's arisen in the human population in the next 10-15000 years.

> "That was when Mohiam selected the particular disease, an oh-so-gradual vengeance, a neurological disorder that would destroy his beautiful body. The Baron’s physique obviously brought him much pleasure, was a source of great pride. She could have infected him with any number of fatal, suppurating plagues— but this affliction would be a deeper blow to him, much slower in its course. She would make the Baron face his own appearance every day as he grew fatter and weaker. His muscles would degenerate, his metabolism would go haywire. In a few years, he wouldn’t even be able to walk by himself"
>
> <sub><sup>*Dune: House Atreides*</sup></sub>

What's most find interesting is that this idea (e.g. that the Baron's condition was given to him by the BG) wasn't in the original Dune series of books, but *was* included in the prequels co-written by Herbert's son, which means that either the author of the encyclopaedia had inside knowledge of genesis of the Baron's condition or that Brian Herbert took the idea *from* the encyclopaedia.

Comment: Another choice has been Brian and Herbert estate’s company line: Brian continued the prequel (and sequel) books like House Harkonnen where we learn this in canon based solely off notes of Frank Herbert and have specifically and affirmatively refuted the Dune Encyclopedia was considered by Brian & KJA.  Also, with House Harkonnen written in 2000, they just could have played on idea of Lynch’s 1984 film Baron’s various afflictions and given them backstory perhaps as easily as they could 1984’s Dune Encyclopedia.

Comment: @SillybutTrue Even if the disease was in Frank Herbert's notes - as I recall the David Lynch depiction of Navigators inspired Frank Herbert to add Navigator "stages" to the book canon.  The disease may be a similar synergy.

Comment: @SillybutTrue - either way I find it quite interesting.  It is either a case of the tail wagging the dog or a peculiar coincidence that they both came up with the same idea (or somehow the encyclopaedia writer got the idea from Frank Herbert).

Comment: But what about the part where gluttony covers up for the disease?

Comment: @einpoklum - The encyclopaedia is full of mild contradictions and inaccuracies. Much like a real encyclopedia, tbh

Comment: @einpoklum - Gluttony would "conceal" the disease by providing a more plausible explanation for sudden massive weight gain.

Comment: @Adamant: Mmm... I dunno. First, it's not sudden. But I guess you could make that argument.

Comment: @einpoklum - If someone goes from Adonis to 1000 pounds or whatever in a few years without a major change in exercise or eating habits,  that is sudden enough to make people wonder.

Comment: @Adamant: A grown man suddenly become so much of a glutton as to merit a weight gain to 1000 pounds is also enough to make people wonder.

Comment: @einpoklum - Of course, but given the choice....